# Integrating GPGS and AdMob or Vungle

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, google-play-games, vungle-ads

Using Unity 5.2.3.
Using Android SDK Rev. 23.1.1
Using Google Play Game Services [Package](http://GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.31a.unitypackage) 0.9.31a (Services Version 8.4.0) for unity.
Using [AdMob](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases/download/v3.0.1/GoogleMobileAds.unitypackage) 3.0.1
Using Vungle (can't link, stackoverflow not allowing more than 2 links)

Note: I am using AdMob and Vungle separately with Play game services.

I have integrated Play game services with my app and that's work fine but whenever I try to include any other packages like AdMob or Vungle following happens.

AdMob: I have included the package, whenever Compile or Reopen the project play-services-basement-8.4.0 get deleted, Play Games Package has Resolve Client Jars and I am 100% sure that to blame.

Vungle: I configured Vungle Package as described in their documentation but again whenever I compile or reopen the Project several of Vungle files along with Vungle's main file Assets/Plugins/Android/libs/"android-support-v4.jar" get deleted. Again maybe Resolve Client Jars to blame.

In both cases above, I have manually copied the missing files and include them while Unity was closed but those were gone as soon as project opens.

I have issued a bug report with Unity but they said they can't help with 3rd party and they don't have issue on Unity's end.

Please Help and let me know any additional information, ill be happy to assist you.

Regards,

Comment: I truly feel your pain; it's unlikely you'll get much answer here.  Did you try answers.unity3d for what it's worth?

Comment: You can turn off the background resolution of the jar reresolver under Assets/Google Play Services/Settings and then see what happens.

Comment: @Joe Blow: Thank you, I have linked this thread in Unity Answers.

Comment: @Clayton Wilkinson:I disabled the jar resolver but no good. I am exactly having the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Since PlayServicesResolver just find dependency by rules and copy "NEWEST" to project folder and Google Play Games already have dependency on support-library-v4 23.1.+. , we can not resolve this within Unity Plugin.

I would recommend:
As work around, you can navigate to Assets>Google Play Services>Settings>uncheck-"enable background resolution" 
and manually copy support library from 
$sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/21.0.3/support-v4-21.0.3.aar 
to 
Assets/Plugins/Android, and run Assets>Google Play Services>Resolve Client Jars and keep 21.0.3"

This will leave "older version" of "android-support-v4.jar", but Google Play Games might not work with this version of "android-support-v4.jar".

Can you please try this?

Thanks!